# Can you submit the same session proposal to two different conferences?

Tags: conference, conflict-of-interest, humanities

Each conference is on a different continent but is in the same discipline 
(A & H). If my proposal is accepted, I will be chairing both sessions but will obviously have different speakers.

I am concerned that the governing associations may not be pleased due to a fear of redundancy.

Is this an academic faux-pas?

An 'emerging scholar'.

Comment: I would let both conference chairs know that you have submitted the proposal to the other conference. And I would check very carefully that both conferences are not mock conferences that exist only to extract large attendance fees from attendees.

Comment: Why must the speakers be different?

Comment: re:Debora Weber-Wulff   The two conferences the  two biggest of its kind in my discipline. I just hope that upon informing both chairs that I will not have  to withdraw should redundancy be an issue.

Comment: re:gerrit        Different speakers in case I get same audience members.

Comment: This may be a discipline specific issue. In my discipline, such duplicate sessions are common. Sometimes some of the same papers will be presented, but conferences are precursors to publication, and conference papers are not themselves considered contributions, at least not meaningfully. In a conference oriented discipline, the norm could be different, similar to submitting the same publication to multiple journals in mine.

Comment: How general is the session proposal? Are you accepting paper submissions for the session, or is it more like an invited discussion panel? Does the conference have a peer review process? If both conferences are peer reviewed, your general session topic would end up being very different at each conference.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, two different conferences with the same session topics will result in two groups of work that are different, but compliment each other.

For example, assume I run a session called "Computer Forensics" at two different conferences. We will either invite different speakers, or use peer review for submissions to the session. In either case the result will likely be two sessions with the same general topic, but very different specific topics.

If the governing associations do not want the same topics, then make the topic title more general, but still related.

Answer (score 1):

"A&H" covers very many different disciplines with different practices.

In philosophy, it would not be strange at all to present the same paper multiply prior to publication (to get objections and feedback). Doing an entire panel with the same people and taking it on tour is something I've never seen. But when I say I've never seen it, I mean that I don't track conferences regularly (they're not important in philosophy in the same way they would be in CS). I don't think there's any rule against it within the discipline.

I cannot speak for other humanities and their practices.